# How to use mapPartitions to implement below map logic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

Here is my scala code using map, I need these 2 lines of codes to be written using mapPartitions. Data is at the bottom.

```
val deckofcardsRDD=sc.textFile("/user/root/decks/deckofcards.txt")
deckofcardsRDD.map(card => card.split("\\|")(2)).countByValue().toList.sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
```

Output

> ```
> (2,4)
> (3,4)
> (4,4)
> (5,4)
> ```

Data

> ```
> BLACK|CLUB|2
> BLACK|CLUB|3
> BLACK|CLUB|4
> BLACK|CLUB|5
> BLACK|SPADE|2
> BLACK|SPADE|3
> BLACK|SPADE|4
> BLACK|SPADE|5
> RED|HEART|2
> RED|HEART|3
> RED|HEART|4
> RED|HEART|5
> RED|DIAMOND|2
> RED|DIAMOND|3
> RED|DIAMOND|4
> RED|DIAMOND|5
> ```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve via `mapPartitions` ?

Comment: I am new to scala and spark, I read that mapPartitions should be used to get higher level of partitioning while processing large amounts of data. I was just looking for implementing same logic as in map using mapPartitions.

Comment: `mapPartitions` can't improve code provided by you here. But it could when you should do something heavy once for large amount of data in a single thread. There is no reason to use more complex mapping in such simple data transformations

Comment: I am aware of that, I just want to test code is functionally working using simple use case and smaller data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out the answer.

Here is the code snippet.

```
val deckofcardsRDD=sc.textFile("/user/root/decks/deckofcards.txt", 13)
deckofcardsRDD.mapPartitions(card => card.map(item => item.split("\\|")(2))).countByValue().toList.sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
```